# retrieve value from a dictionary inside a list, inside a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to return the most recent "low" and "high" values into variables and am not sure how to retrieve them.

The code I am running is:

```
def get_price_history(**kwargs):
    url = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory'.format(kwargs.get('symbol'))
    params = {}
    params.update({'apikey': key})

    for arg in kwargs:
        parameter = {arg: kwargs.get(arg)}
        params.update(parameter)

    return requests.get(url, params=params).json()


print(get_price_history(symbol='AAPL', period=1, periodType='day', frequencyType='minute'))
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
{'candles': [{'open': 129.99, 'high': 130.07, 'low': 129.97, 'close': 130.05, 'volume': 7287, 'datetime': 1620385200000}, {'open': 130.04, 'high': 130.05, 'low': 130.0, 'close': 130.0, 'volume': 4922, 'datetime': 1620385260000},
```

This continues on for quite awhile. How do I retrieve the values from the above function?

Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say

```
results = {'candles': [{'open': 129.99, 'high': 130.07, 'low': 129.97, 'close': 130.05, 'volume': 7287, 'datetime': 1620385200000}, {'open': 130.04, 'high': 130.05, 'low': 130.0, 'close': 130.0, 'volume': 4922, 'datetime': 1620385260000}]}
```

Get record with max datetime as such:

```
maxDatetimeObj = max(results['candles'], key=lambda x:x['datetime'])
```

Get low and high from max datetime

```
low = maxDatetimeObj['low']
high = maxDatetimeObj['high']
```